# Populate without _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have 2 mongoose schemas, one for `stock` (info about stock) and one for `trade`. Where trade represents the trades of a `stock` (so time, volume, etc). Each `stock` has a symbol code and the data feed that I get the trades from includes the symbol codes as strings. How would I populate these two collections since I can't use the regular mongoose `'ref'` here.

Here are my two schemas:

```
const stockSchema = new Schema({
  symbolCode: { type: String, trim: true },
  symbol: { type: String, trim: true },
  type: { type: String, index: true, trim: true },
  country: { type: String, lowercase: true }
})

 const tradeSchema = new Schema({
  symbolCode: { type: String, index: true },
  symbol: { type: String, index: true },
  price: Number,
  volume: Number,
  time: Date,
  currency: { type: String, default: 'USD', uppercase: true, index: true }
})
```

I want to remove the first two fields in the `trade` schema so that I can just have some kind of reference to the stock here. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

use the populate like this:
`MyModel.populate([{ path: 'author', select: 'username name -_id' }]);`

the `-fieldName` or in your case `-_id` will deduct it from the projection.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I solved this using [populate virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) as follows:

```
 stockSchema.virtual('trades', {
  ref: 'Trade',
  localField: 'symbolCode',
  foreignField: 'symbolCode',
  justOne: true
})
```